# expressionEngine php parsing str_replace not working

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have a template with php enabled on output. However i can't get str_replace to work. See below code. If i just put {title} without any php then it works. But when i include php and place {title} inside the str_replace function, i get nothing displayed. I tried php with simple echo 'test'; and it worked. It's just not parsing {title} or other field tags.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="one" url_title="{segment_2}"}
  <?php
    echo str_replace('old', 'new', '{title}');
  ?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound preposterous, but have you tried removing the `url_title` parameter from the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag to ensure the rest of your code and logic is working properly?

The following code should output the entry title of "old test" (without quotes):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" entry_id="xx" dynamic="off"}
    {title} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Given the same entry title of "old test", this should output: "new test" (again, without the quotes):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" entry_id="xx" dynamic="off"}
    <?php
        echo str_replace('old', 'new', '{title}');
    ?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This was tested successfully in a new, blank template with **PHP Enabled** and set to **Output**.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @thanks @rjb, I should have used `segment_3` instead of `segment_2`. it does work now,  However if i have the following str_replace array of words, it doesn't work. php doesn't seem to recognize title. 
  `$searchArray = array("on", "two", "thre", "fou");
  $replaceArray = array("one", "two", "three", "four");
  $intoString = "{title}";
  echo str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $intoString);` Any reason why `{title}` is not recognized here.

Comment: This following code worked for me: [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9odhR.png) or [Pastie](http://pastie.org/pastes/2175892/text)

Answer (score 0):

You might try embedding the template that has your PHP in it and sending the variable that way. The parsing on input/output still doesn't matter with certain elements sometimes.

Comment: This is not a solution.  The only way to know what i'm talking about is to try it yourself.